# App links working when using adb but not when using url in browser

Tags: android, flutter

I have added assetlinks.json to my domain and I have verified ith

https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

When my app is install I can see the link as verified under settings, and if I use adb like this:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://my-domain.org/login?code=sdfsdfsdf"
```

It works, my app is opened. But if I type in "https://my-domain.org/login?code=sdfsdfsdf" in Chrome on the device, it simply open the URL in the Chrome browser and does not open my app.

Here is my AndroidManifest part:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="${appIcon}"
    android:label="My app">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="my-domain.org"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any ideas please?

Best regards
Søren

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, app is opening but its not opening through browser, Its opening directly. So i have doubt if its actually doing verification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I type in "https://my-domain.org/login?code=sdfsdfsdf" in Chrome on the device, it simply open the URL in the Chrome browser and does not open my app

AFAICT, that is working as intended. App links are for *links*, not manually-entered URLs.

Create a Web page. Put a link to `https://my-domain.org/login?code=sdfsdfsdf` in the Web page. Load the Web page in Chrome. Click the link. Then, if app links are set up correctly, it should work.

Comment: You are correct, thank you. So it is the redirect that is not working, now at lease I have a direction

Comment: oh mannnnnnnnnnnnnn, @CommonWare this guy deserves a Medal, saved my 9999999 hours of time. I kept freaking entering the url on my phone browser and did nothing for hours until I found this solution. It works! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Commonware I am also facing similar issue, app is opening but its not opening through browser, Its opening directly. So i have doubt if its actually doing verification?

Comment: @Prateek: Use an Android 12 or higher device and [manually see if the verification is enabled](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification).

Comment: I see that url is coming as verified i only had doubt because it navigates very smooth in my my case from one app to other but if i see amazon or any other app they shows chrome page first and then navigating.